# What Gtk signal should I use: key-press-event or key-release-event for catching return key in a GtkEntry?

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I am trying to catch the enter/return key in a `GtkEntry` widget. Should I make a signal hander for `key-press-event` or `key-release event`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to catch the "activate" signal instead?

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you could look at connecting to the "activate" signal which gets fired when the user hits enter or activates it through some other method.

Answer (score 3):

It depends when you want to act on the event as either signal will do. If you handle key-press-event and the user holds down the key, then you'll keep getting signals. If you handle key-release-event then you'll only get one signal when the user releases the key.

I think most commonly you'll want to use key-release-event.